# Index file size limit

Tags: c#, .net, lucene, lucene.net

I have an indexing application which uses lucene index to index the documents and the index could grow up-to 10 GB.

Is there any size limit for lucene index?

Comment: this post might help you with your enquiry: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65406/how-do-i-estimate-the-size-of-a-lucene-index

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no file size limit for indexes. However there are limits on the number of terms and the number of documents that can be indexed. See the bottom of [this page](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-ALPHA/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene40/package-summary.html#Limitations) for those limits.